# check checkbox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to autocheck a checkbox (terms & condition) in a checkout page with javascript when my chrome extension is running but any code I have tried are not working. The website is https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all. You need to add an item in the basket to go to the checkout page and there you can find the checkbox.

I already fillup the rest of the information in the checkout and just missing the autocheck the checkbox.

This is one of the code I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("order_terms").checked  = true;
```

I have also tried get element by class, name and trying with all the different id, names that I have found in inspect (f12). I am trying all this code on the google chrome console for testing purpose.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: That checkbox _does_ get checked, the box replacing it just doesn’t display it. How about `if(!document.getElementById("order_terms").checked){ document.getElementById("order_terms").nextElementSibling.click(); }`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon thank you! that was what I was looking for! Didn't know about nextElementSibling. I'll do some research to understand it more.

Comment: @Faiyaz `nextElementSibling` is just part of the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) for basic DOM traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the website is using something called icheckbox. It's a replacement for the normal checkbox and needs an additional class, `.checked` to be added to it before it visually displays as checked.

```js
<div class="icheckbox_minimal checked" style="position: relative;">
  {...rest of your checkbox html}
</div>
```